# /var/log/messages getting huge in size

Tags: centos7

I am using CentOS 7 and facing issues with /var/log/messages. For some reason, /var/log/messages gets huge in size filling up the whole partition. To resolve the issue, every time in have to empty the file but it get huge again.

Can anyone please advise permanent solution on this?

Comment: Read the log file, find out what's filling it, solve the actual problem.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider I have checked that, the log are fine, it looks like log rotation is not working somehow

Comment: If you want to fix your logrotate configuration you should provide it.